# Keras 2 input model, incompatible Shapes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build a two input model with keras, with each input being a string.

Here's the code for the model

```
    vectorize_layer1 = TextVectorization(split="character", output_sequence_length=512,
                                         max_tokens=MAX_STRING_SIZE)
    vectorize_layer1.adapt(list(vocab))

    # define two sets of inputs
    inputA = Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string)
    inputB = Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string)

    # the first branch operates on the first input
    x = vectorize_layer1(inputA)
    x = Embedding(len(vectorize_layer1.get_vocabulary()), MAX_STRING_SIZE)(x)
    x = Bidirectional(LSTM(MAX_STRING_SIZE, return_sequences=True, dropout=.2))(x)
    x = LSTM(MAX_STRING_SIZE, activation="tanh", return_sequences=False, dropout=.2)(x)
    x = Model(inputs=inputA, outputs=x)

    # the second branch opreates on the second input
    y = vectorize_layer1(inputB)
    y = Embedding(len(vectorize_layer1.get_vocabulary()), MAX_STRING_SIZE)(y)
    y = Bidirectional(LSTM(MAX_STRING_SIZE, return_sequences=True, dropout=.2))(y)
    y = LSTM(MAX_STRING_SIZE, activation="tanh", return_sequences=False, dropout=.2)(y)
    y = Model(inputs=inputB, outputs=y)

    # combine the output of the two branches
    combined = concatenate([x.output, y.output])
    # apply a FC layer and then a prediction on the categories
    z = Dense(2, activation="relu")(combined)
    z = Dense(len(LABELS), activation="softmax")(z)

    # our model will accept the inputs of the two branches an
    model = Model(inputs=[x.input, y.input], outputs=z)
    print(model.predict((np.array(["i love python"]), np.array(["test"]))))
    #That prediction works fine! 

    model.summary()
    plot_model(model, to_file="model.png", show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
    model.compile(optimizer='Adam',
                  loss=CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
                  metrics=["categorical_accuracy"])

    stopper = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_categorical_accuracy', patience=10)
    checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint("model-best.tf", save_best_only=True)


    model.fit(
        training,
        callbacks=[stopper, checkpointer],
        steps_per_epoch=2048,
        validation_data=validation,
        batch_size=8,
        epochs=epochs
    )
    model.save(output, save_format='tf')
```

I'm getting the Shapes are incompatible error though:

```
 line 5119, in categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 20) are incompatible
```

Here is an example of the training/validation data:

```
((array(['foo'], dtype='<U6'), array(['bar'], dtype='<U26')), array([0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]))
```

Any ideas what is going wrong? The data looks ok to me, the categories are 1-hot encoded.

[image: Model diagram]

Here is the stack trace:

```
ValueError: in user code:

    File "/Users/**/code/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/Users/**/code/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1040, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/Users/**/code/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1030, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/Users/**/code/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 890, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/Users/**/code/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 948, in compute_loss
        return self.compiled_loss(
    File "/Users/**/code/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 201, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/Users/**/code/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 139, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/Users/**/code/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 243, in call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/Users/**/code/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/losses.py", line 1787, in categorical_crossentropy
        return backend.categorical_crossentropy(
    File "/Users/**/code/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/backend.py", line 5119, in categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 20) are incompatible
```

Comment: Is the error message is coming from model.fit(...)? If it is could you add the code for that call please?

Comment: Yes, it errors in model.fit()

Comment: I added the stack trace and the code above

Comment: Thanks. Am I right to think 'training' is a tf dataset (and not a generator, say)?

Comment: `training` is a generator actually

Comment: ```((array(['foo'], dtype='<U6'), array(['bar'], dtype='<U26')), array([0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0.]))``` it returns a tuple of ((array, array), array)

Comment: OK, I'm going to post a tentative answer based around a dataset, but I think the same issue would probably apply to a generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain this is the issue, but it does show that
categorical_crossentropy can object to a tensor of shape (n) in a
tensorflow dataset, as you seem to have, demanding instead a tensor of shape (1,n)

It's too long to post as a comment anyway, so I can only post it as an 'answer'

In the code below, I'm creating a tf dataset like yours with one row,
and with Y.shape (n). The categorical_crossentropy loss won't accept
it, but does work if Y.shape is (1,6)

(I don't, I'm afraid, know how to make the reshaping work without setting
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True), but that may not be an issue for you
it you are using a generator)

Here's my minimal model and dataset setup:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True) # tf.autograph objects to something about the reshape 

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(((np.array([[0.]]),np.array([[1.]])),np.array([[8., 3., 0., 8., 2., 1.]])))

# Even though the original array had shape (1,6), the dataset element has shape (6)
print(f"dataset y shape: {[row[1].shape for row in dataset]}")

# -- create and compile model, 2 inputs, one output
inp1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,))
inp2 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,))
x = tf.concat([inp1, inp2], axis=1)
y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(6)(x)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[inp1, inp2], outputs=y)
model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
```

Then this fails, with a similar error to yours:

```py
history = model.fit(dataset, epochs=1)
```

but this succeeds, after reshaping y from (6) to (1,6):

```py
def reshaper(x, y):
    return x, tf.expand_dims(y, 0)
dataset2 = dataset.map(reshaper)
print(f"dataset2 y shape: {[row[1].shape for row in dataset2]}")

history = model.fit(dataset2, epochs=1)
```

Comment: That did it! I'll award the bounty in 20 hours. Thanks!!!

Comment: Many thanks, much appreciated. Do you feel this is a bug in categorical_cross_entropy, incidentally? It appears to treat the first dimension of Y as indexing training example - it's not behaviour I was expecting, but am unsure if there may be a reason for it to do this.

Comment: Its definitely strange to me, not sure if its a bug though?

Answer (score 1):

Hidden units in output layer should be 1.

```
z = Dense(1, activation="softmax")(z)
```

Comment: I have 20 different labels, so it has to be 20 though :)